# Yii 1.1: how to track ALL requests with database persistence?

Tags: php, yii

I would like to solve very simple and yet important task:

> How to track **ALL** requests coming to Yii regardless of whether they could be served or not.

I have the following database scheme:

```
day    relative_url    count
```

all I need is to update *count* for a particular day when user requests a specific url.

**What I have.** Tried to do it using

```
Controller
|_ beforeAction($action)
```

but it seems to be tracking only resolvable requests.

**P.S.** It would be even better if I can track with what status a particular request was served to the user. Main interest is statuses 200 and 404.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a model for your tracking request table and add a method to it that stores that information and run it in the main.php under protected/views/layouts/. Every request is going to run though the main.php so you know you'll capture every request that goes though. For example:

(inside the model)

```
public function storeRequestData(){
   $url = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
   $time = time();

   //store values here and increment count
}
```

(inside main.php)

```
TrackingTable::model()->storeRequestData()
```